# do not count certain positions in character when replacing certain character positions (in R)

Tags: r, character

So, I know my title is a little bit confusing but I was hoping you could help me out here.

I have this data frame `df` where one column is a RNA sequence alignment. The class of this column is a character.
And then I have these other columns: "Allele_1", "Allele_2" which represent the variants of a single position in the RNA sequence (column 1) and that position is given by column 3 ("Position"). However those positions do not account for the "-", i.e., for instance in row 2 the position of the alleles is `U--ACC`**G**`U--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD` **and NOT** `U--A`**C**`CGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD`.

```
sequence                         Allele_1   Allele_2     Position
UAAGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa     A          U            3
U--ACCGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD    C          G            5
cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T       U          C            2
```

The length of the sequence in column 1 can be variable.

What I want to do is to replace specific letters of the character in specific locations given by "position" and the replacement is given by "Allele_1" and "Allele_2". For instance if the position matches "Allele_2", then I want to replace it by "Allele_2" and vice-versa.

I have tried:

```
substr(df[,"sequence"], 
  start = df[,"Position"], 
  stop = df[,"Position"]) <- df[,"Allele_1"]
```

However because my position column does not take into account the "-", it replaces in the wrong place. For instance and back to row 2, it replaces here `U--A`**C**`CGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD`instead of here `U--ACC`**G**`U--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD`.
Also I haven't figure out how to do "the position matches "Allele_2", then I want to replace it by "Allele_2" and vice-versa" thing.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

Really hoping that you can help me figure this out!!

Cheers!

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, it's supposed to be "if the position matches "Allele_1", then I want to replace it by "Allele_2" and vice-versa" **and not** "Allele_2", then I want to replace it by "Allele_2".

Comment: If it's a small df, to work out which character number to change, you could iterate through each character and increase an iterator only if the character wasn't '-'.  That would be slow though.

Comment: @ds440 Unfortunately my df is bigger than this one I showed and the length of the sequences is really big, as in 5 digits big, although it my vary a lot. So i was really hoping to find an alternative way to do this, instead of doing it manually one by one. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Have you looked in Bioconductor for any solutions?  Biostrings masking seems to have incomplete documentation but might have a solution, possibly multiple alignment packages might have something

Comment: If no good existing solution can be find, the iterator / character matching I mentioned above would probably be pretty quick if implemented in C(++) using Rcpp or similar.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "if the position matches `Allele_2`, then I want to replace it with `Allele_2`"? Isn't that replacing a letter with itself? Generally, a good approach here is list columns, though; `df$seq_list <- strsplit(df$sequence, '')`, and then you can subset each element, e.g. `df$to_replace <- mapply(function(seq, pos){seq[seq != '-'][pos]}, df$seq_list, df$Position)`

Comment: @alistaire Using strsplit uses quite a bit more RAM.  A 1e6 long string takes up 1MB, but after strsplit it uses 8MB.

Comment: The most direct way would be to use regex, but it requires some chops and potentially some processing power: `mapply(function(seq, pos){sub(paste0('(?:-*(?:\\w)-*){', pos - 1, '}(\\w).*'), '\\1', seq)}, df$sequence, df$Position)`. And it's still unclear what's supposed to be substituted.

Comment: @alistaire and @ds440 thanks for your input. Unfortunately I cannot subset the "-" from my sequence because i will need to use it latter on. And if i subset it now, i dont know how to get them back in the exact same position they were subsetted. That's why i had the problem in the first place. Regarding the "`if the position matches Allele_2, then I want to replace it with Allele_2`" it was a typing error. Sorry, it was a bit late for me! Just made an update on my question. By the way I will try your solution @ds440 ! Talk to you in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options. Both are case-sensitive and thus don't replace anything in the third sequence. If you don't want them to be, wrap the appropriate variables in the `ifelse`s in `toupper`.

---

#### `strsplit`

You can split each sequence into a vector of letters, against which you can then check equality directly. Implemented in `mapply`, the multivariate version of `sapply`:

```
df$new_seq <- mapply(function(seq, a1, a2, pos){
    seq <- strsplit(seq, '')[[1]]    # split into letters
    to_replace <- seq[seq != '-'][pos]    # identify allele to replace
    # assign appropriate replacement to subset
    seq[seq != '-'][pos] <- ifelse(a1 == to_replace, 
                                   a2, ifelse(a2 == to_replace, 
                                              a1, to_replace))
    paste(seq, collapse = '')    # reassemble vector to string
}, df$sequence, df$Allele_1, df$Allele_2, df$Position)

df
##                        sequence Allele_1 Allele_2 Position                       new_seq
## 1  UAAGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa        A        U        3  UAUGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa
## 2 U--ACCGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD        C        G        5 U--ACCCU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD
## 3    cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T        U        C        2    cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T
```

If you prefer, you can break the operation into multiple steps, assigning the result of each to a variable.

---

#### `sub` (regex)

If you're comfortable with regex, you can assemble expressions to extract the allele in question and then replace it with the appropriate replacement:

```
df$to_replace <- mapply(function(seq, pos){
    sub(paste0('(?:-*(?:\\w)-*){', pos - 1, '}(\\w).*'), '\\1', seq)
}, df$sequence, df$Position)

df$new_seq <- mapply(function(seq, pos, a1, a2, to_rpl){
    replacement <- ifelse(to_rpl == a1, a2, ifelse(to_rpl == a2, a1, to_rpl))
    sub(paste0('((?:-*(?:\\w)-*){', pos - 1, '})\\w(.*)'), 
        paste0('\\1', replacement, '\\2'), 
        seq)
}, df$sequence, df$Position, df$Allele_1, df$Allele_2, df$to_replace)

df[-5]
##                        sequence Allele_1 Allele_2 Position                       new_seq
## 1  UAAGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa        A        U        3  UAUGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa
## 2 U--ACCGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD        C        G        5 U--ACCCU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD
## 3    cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T        U        C        2    cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T
```

Comment: Looks like the `strsplit` method is fastest (see benchmarks in my answer).

Comment: Interesting, and not wholly surprising, I guess. For me, base fails at 255, and PCRE (with `perl = TRUE`) at 3855. `stringr::str_replace` (and the `stringi` it leverages) were as big as I tried—over 150000—without any issues.

Comment: alistaire and @ds440 thanks a lot! You totally saved me!

Answer (score 0):

## Data

I created a first, small dataframe, and a larger more realistic data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(sequence = c('UAAGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa',
                                  'U--ACCGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD',
                                  'cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T'),
                     Allele_1 = c('A', 'C', 'U'),
                     Allele_2 = c('U', 'G', 'C'),
                     Position = c(3, 5, 2))

df_big <- data.frame(sequence = rep(c(paste(rep('UAAGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa', 100), collapse=''),
                                  paste(rep('U--ACCGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD', 100), collapse=''),
                                  paste(rep('cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T', 100), collapse='')), 100),
                 Allele_1 = rep(c('A', 'C', 'U'), 100),
                 Allele_2 = rep(c('U', 'G', 'C'), 100),
                 Position = rep(c(1000, 1000, 1000), 100))
```

## Functions

I created a function to return the 'new' position after the multiple alignment (ie not counting `-`), that works with vectors, as follows; also a faster but less safe function:

```
find_pos <- function(string, pos) {
  vectorized <- data.frame(string=string, pos=pos)
  sapply(seq_len(nrow(vectorized)), function(i) {
    guess <- vectorized[i,'pos']; oldguess <- 0
    offset <- -1; trynum <- 0
    while(offset != 0 & trynum < 500) {
      offset <- nchar(gsub('[^-]', '', substr(vectorized[i,'string'], oldguess+1, guess)))
      oldguess <- guess
      guess <- oldguess + offset
      trynum <- trynum+1
    }
    return(guess)
  })
}

find_pos_unsafe <- function(string, pos) {
  sapply(seq_along(string), function(i) {
    guess <- pos[i]; oldguess <- 0
    offset <- -1
    while(offset != 0) {
      offset <- nchar(gsub('[^-]', '', substr(string[i], oldguess+1, guess)))
      oldguess <- guess
      guess <- oldguess + offset
    }
    return(guess)
  })
}
```

The first can be used with different length variables as follows (but incurs an overhead for this flexibility):

```
> find_pos(string, 1:5)
[1] 1 4 5 6 7
```

For benchmarking purposes I've wrapped the other code required to get the solution in a function.  Again, two forms, one calling the faster matching function and one calling the safer version:

```
ds440 <- function(df) {
pos <- find_pos(df$sequence, df$Position)
toswap <- ifelse(substr(df$sequence, pos, pos)==df$Allele_1, as.character(df$Allele_2), #if A1, A2
                 ifelse(substr(df$sequence, pos, pos)==df$Allele_2, as.character(df$Allele_1), #If A2, A1
                        substr(df$sequence, pos, pos))) # else keep same

df$replaced <- as.character(df$sequence)
substr(df$replaced, pos, pos) <- as.character(toswap)

df
}

ds440_quick <- function(df) {
  pos <- find_pos_unsafe(df$sequence, df$Position)
  toswap <- ifelse(substr(df$sequence, pos, pos)==df$Allele_1, as.character(df$Allele_2), #if A1, A2
                   ifelse(substr(df$sequence, pos, pos)==df$Allele_2, as.character(df$Allele_1), #If A2, A1
                          substr(df$sequence, pos, pos))) # else keep same

  df$replaced <- as.character(df$sequence)
  substr(df$replaced, pos, pos) <- toswap

  df
}
```

Other functions adapted from @alistaire

```
alistaire_split <- function(df) {
  df$new_seq <- mapply(function(seq, a1, a2, pos){
    seq <- strsplit(seq, '')[[1]]    # split into letters
    to_replace <- seq[seq != '-'][pos]    # identify allele to replace
    # assign appropriate replacement to subset
    seq[seq != '-'][pos] <- ifelse(a1 == to_replace, 
                                   a2, ifelse(a2 == to_replace, 
                                              a1, to_replace))
    paste(seq, collapse = '')    # reassemble vector to string
  }, as.character(df$sequence), as.character(df$Allele_1), as.character(df$Allele_2), df$Position)

  df
}

alistaire_sub <- function(df) {
  df$to_replace <- mapply(function(seq, pos){
    sub(paste0('(?:-*(?:\\w)-*){', pos - 1, '}(\\w).*'), '\\1', seq)
  }, df$sequence, df$Position)

  df$new_seq <- mapply(function(seq, pos, a1, a2, to_rpl){
    replacement <- ifelse(to_rpl == a1, a2, ifelse(to_rpl == a2, a1, to_rpl))
    sub(paste0('((?:-*(?:\\w)-*){', pos - 1, '})\\w(.*)'), 
        paste0('\\1', replacement, '\\2'), 
        seq)
  }, df$sequence, df$Position, df$Allele_1, df$Allele_2, df$to_replace)

  df[-5]
}
```

## Results

Note the case sensitivity in the matching above.  Use `toupper` or similar before checking for equality if you don't care about case.

```
ds440(df)
                       sequence Allele_1 Allele_2 Position                      replaced
1  UAAGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa        A        U        3  UAUGGCUCA----UAGGCAGAU--AUaa
2 U--ACCGU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD        C        G        5 U--ACCCU--G----UAUUUGAU--CTAD
3    cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T        U        C        2    cctaACCGU-UUAGCC---------T
```

### Benchmarking

Functions were defined above.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(ds440(df), ds440_quick(df), alistaire_split(df), alistaire_sub(df))
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
           ds440(df) 727.157 747.0065 801.3529 764.1475 781.6400 3658.410   100   c
     ds440_quick(df) 339.784 354.7140 364.4484 364.1440 370.7955  421.400   100  b 
 alistaire_split(df) 138.929 144.9500 150.6806 148.5890 153.8570  261.136   100 a  
   alistaire_sub(df) 815.853 833.6630 855.2414 844.0770 857.2130 1499.370   100   c

microbenchmark(ds440(df_big), ds440_quick(df_big), alistaire_split(df_big))
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
           ds440(df_big) 195.4233 199.2827 204.4030 204.9039 208.0195 216.1879   100   c
     ds440_quick(df_big) 136.5985 139.3442 143.7216 145.1585 146.7837 153.9201   100 a  
 alistaire_split(df_big) 138.9117 146.3977 150.8772 148.2299 151.0723 278.7308   100  b
```

Clear winner for time in the small examle is @`alistaire`'s split function, however as the df gets bigger, the `alistaire_sub` function breaks (regex won't handle >999) and my `ds440_quick` function actually works out slightly faster.

Comment: is there any way that `string` and `pos` can be a char [1:29] ? when i define `string <- df[,"sequence"]` and `pos <- df[,"position"]` it gives me this warning: `1: In while (offset != 0 & trynum < 500) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. Otherwise if i define one by one string and pos, it works out fine! Just really hoped i could do this more quickly.

Comment: I've made changes to allow vector input.